# Android - Upload Image to server folder and post Image URL in to My SQL Database table Using Volley library

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, android-volley

I need to upload image to server folder and as well as I need to post that uploaded URL to my SQL database table using volley

I have code for to capture the image or pick from the gallery

```
 private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UpdateStatusActivity.this);
        // builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), 2);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }



 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                rlImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgUploadImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                // String drawableId = (String)imgUploadImage.getTag().toString();
                // Log.w("imagee", drawableId);
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                        null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
                int scale = 1;
                while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                        && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;
                options.inSampleSize = scale;
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                rlImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgUploadImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

from this code am getting image to image view so now I need to upload that image to the server folder and post that uploaded image URL to my SQL table using volley.

Comment: These are two questions. (and two problems) you would do well to ask two separate questions (and to simplify the task for yourself by working on them as two separate problems)

Comment: please if u know give any code or example, Thank you in advance

Comment: sorry this is not a code writing service. Help others help you by posting two seperate questions. Or if you search how to upload an image with volley, how to post data to my server with volley you will probably find answers to both.